# Spring Data Specifications - RSQL with join

Tags: java, spring-boot, join, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to develop a search API with Specification and RSQL. Followed this tutorial - https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-rsql-fiql

I have a User entity which have a OneToOne relation with UserProfile.

```
@Entity
public class User{

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = UserProfile.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "user_profile_id")
    private UserProfile userProfile;
...

@Entity
public class UserProfile{

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String education;

    ...
```

And Predicate function,

```
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
    List<Object> args = castArguments(root);
    Object argument = args.get(0);

    switch (RsqlSearchOperation.getSimpleOperator(operator)) {

    case EQUAL: {
            if (argument instanceof String) {               
                return builder.like(root.get(property), argument.toString().replace('*', '%'));
            } else if (argument == null) {
                return builder.isNull(root.get(property));
            } else {
                return builder.equal(root.get(property), argument);
            }
        }
        case NOT_EQUAL: {
```

....

When i call the API with parameter ?search=firstName==John , it's returning results as expected. What i need is search by education and return Users having that education. I tried with Join as follows, but it's not working.

```
if (argument instanceof String) {
                Join<User, UserProfile> profileJoin = root.join("user_profile_id");

                return builder.like(root.get(property), profileJoin.get(property));
            } else if (argument == null) {
```

Any solution with generic will be really helpful.

Comment: Use this library https://github.com/tennaito/rsql-jpa, userProfile.education=='something' will do the job

Comment: A simpler alternative might be https://github.com/mhewedy/spring-data-jpa-mongodb-expressions where you can send the intuitive and easy-to-use MongoDB queries to query JPA repositories. It supports join and many cool features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no concrete solution with generic. So i did it which is close to being generic.

```
switch (RsqlSearchOperation.getSimpleOperator(operator)) {

        case EQUAL: {
            if (doesClassContainProperty(UserProfile.class, property)) {
                Join<User, UserProfile> profileJoin = root.join("user_profile_id");
                return builder.equal(profileJoin.get(property), argument);
            } else {
                return builder.equal(root.get(property), argument);
            }
        }
```

And here is the method to check whether passed param is in root class or join class

```
public boolean doesClassContainProperty(Class<?> genericClass, String fieldName) {
        return Arrays.stream(genericClass.getDeclaredFields()).anyMatch(f -> f.getName().equals(fieldName));
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same for more than one UserProfile fields? When I implemented this, I get two different joins for each UserProfile fields

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend you another library, which lets you build dynamic filters without having to mess with coding, it supports logical operators, comparators, enums, dates, booleans, searching over relations/joins (no n+1 query problem), functions, and much more: https://github.com/turkraft/spring-filter

Example query:

> */search?filter=* **average**(ratings) **>** 4.5 **and** brand.name **in** ('audi', 'land rover') **and** (year **>** 2018 **or** km **<** 50000) and color **:** 'white' **and** accidents **is empty**

Usage:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/search")
public List<Entity> search(@EntityFilter Specification<Entity> spec, Pageable page) {
  return repo.findAll(spec, page);
}
```

Don't forget the dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.turkraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-filter</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```